# How can you find the size of a delta table quickly and accurately?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

The microsoft documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/sql/find-size-of-table#size-of-a-delta-table
suggests two methods:

Method 1:

```
import com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe._
val deltaLog = DeltaLog.forTable(spark, "dbfs:/<path-to-delta-table>")
val snapshot = deltaLog.snapshot               // the current delta table snapshot
println(s"Total file size (bytes): ${deltaLog.snapshot.sizeInBytes}")`
```

Method 2:

```
spark.read.table("<non-delta-table-name>").queryExecution.analyzed.stats
```

For my table, they both return ~300 MB.

But then in storage explorer Folder statistics or in a recursive dbutils.fs.ls walk, I get ~900MB.

So those two methods that are much quicker than literally looking at every file underreport by 67%.  This would be fine to use the slower methods except when I try to scale up to the entire container, it takes 55 hours to scan all 1 billion files and 2.6 PB.

So what is the best way to get the size of a table in ADLS Gen 2?  Bonus points if it works for folders that are not tables as that's really the number I need.  dbutils.fs.ls is single threaded and only works on the driver, so it's not even very parallelizable.  It can be threaded but only within the driver.

Comment: how many versions do you have in the Delta Lake?

Comment: @AlexOtt, not sure if I understand the question--one version is created every time there's an update or delete operation, right?   So across an entire data lake, it's undetermined without traversing it.

Comment: look into `DESCRIBE HISTORY`

Answer (score 1):

`deltaLog.snapshot` returns just the current snapshot. You can have more files present in table's directory, those belong to historical versions that have been deleted/replaced from the current snapshot.

Also it returns 0 without complaints for non-delta paths. So I'm using this piece of code to get a database-level summary:

```
import com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe._
 
val databasePath = "dbfs:/<path-to-database>"
 
def size(path: String): Long =
  dbutils.fs.ls(path).map { fi => if (fi.isDir) size(fi.path) else fi.size }.sum
 
val tables = dbutils.fs.ls(databasePath).par.map { fi =>
  val totalSize = size(fi.path)
  val snapshotSize = DeltaLog.forTable(spark, fi.path).snapshot.sizeInBytes
  (fi.name, totalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, snapshotSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
}
display(tables.seq.sorted.toDF("name", "total_size_gb", "snapshot_size_gb"))
```

This does parallelize on driver only, still it's only file listing, so it's pretty fast. I admit I don't have a billion files, but well, if it's slow for you just use a bigger driver and [tune the number of threads](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html#task-support).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is accurate but not quick, so I'm not going to mark it as a correct answer.  It may be helpful for someone in the future though.

Answer (score -2):

Got answer from https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009MIRSDSA5/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-table-in-python-or-sql

```
%python
spark.sql("describe detail schema.delta_table_name").select("sizeInBytes").collect()
```

Comment: This answer is quick, but not accurate.  It does not accurately reflect the size on disk.  I just tested it on one of our larger tables and while the method using dbutils.fs.ls returns 39 terabytes, this method only returns 1.3 terabytes.  Drastically underreporting.